# Marketing Cloud, changes to template after content blocks added

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder, email-studio

We have a lot of template based emails (around 15 emails in 13 languages).

I want to change the template and update the style.  However this doesn't seem to be reflected in the emails that get sent out.

Is it possible to update the template and have the emails adjust, or do I need to create all the emails again from scratch using the new template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating all emails using the template is currently not available in Content Builder, however you can update the emails one by one instead of creating new emails. You can find a detailed guide in the marketing cloud documentation: [Updating an Email with a Modified Template](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/templates/updating_an_email_with_a_modified_template/)

**Basically it involves following steps:**

1. Go to the email using the template
2. Click on Edit -> Content
3. Under "Template" select "Update Email Now"
4. Click "Next" and "Save"

**Edit:**
Meanwhile "reference content" has been introduced in Marketing Cloud which can also be used in templates. Reference content adds a specific content block in a template and stores a reference to it. At send-time the most recent version of that referenced content block is then included in the email. For information on how to use this type fo content, check out the documentation article ["Add a Reference Block"](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_add_a_reference_block.htm&type=5)

Comment: This is a truly awful platform, making the simplest of things difficult.

Comment: I hope updating emails will be improved in future releases, but until then I'm afraid this is the only option. If my answer helped, please accept my answer so others can see this solved your problem. Thank you!

Comment: I agree that a button to "apply changes to all emails using this template" would be awesome. But, clicking on buttons keeps some people employed! Other people keep themselves busy with the not so simple things Marketing Cloud can do that other platforms can't. I'd consider clueing up on dynamic content and AMPScript, if you've built all these emails separately for each language. It was a bad approach.

Comment: I get to clean up the mess that a crappy consultancy created for us.

Comment: Thanks @Macca your suggestion helped me out a lot! I just used AMPScript to call in header and footer instead of making it a template! Still a stupid setup, but this works until they make it better